# PHP: Should I use sleep or cron to conditionally wait 5 minutes?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, cron, sleep

I have a script that gets triggered when files get uploaded. However, I'd like to only execute this script once all files in a batch are uploaded. A batch, in this case, is all the files that the person wants to upload within a short interval of time, say 5 minutes. There is no way to distinguish a batch from a single file upload aside from the time between individual uploads. The reason why I want to react to a batch rather than individual files is to, hopefully, save on processing of the uploaded files. The 5 minute delay is acceptable since the purpose of the processing is not super time sensitive.

I know 2 ways that could accomplish this: using the sleep function or using cron.

With the sleep function, script 1 would get triggered by an upload and work something like this:

script 1

```
if temp file exists
  delete temp file
  create temp file
else
  create temp file
  run script 2
```

script 2

```
if temp file exists 
  if temp file was created < 5 minutes ago
    sleep(300) //5 minutes
  else
    delete the file
    process uploads
```

With the cron, the scripts will look pretty much the same, just the sleep function would be replaced by a call to cron, likely through a third party library, to schedule the scrip to re-run in 5 minutes.

If you'd like more context, the file uploads I'm talking about are to AWS S3, and the script gets triggered by a lambda function that's listening on all S3 file creation events. Maybe that context will help coming up with a better AWS-specific solution, but so far I haven't found any.

Should I use sleep or cron to accomplish this? I'm open to other suggestions as well.

EDIT:

I will be revising my processing script to react to individual files that get uploaded instead of trying to batch them before processing. I should be able to send the exact link to the file so that there's no overhead on scanning which one was the file that changed.

Comment: If you have access to cron then I would use that rather than relying on user hits to trigger jobs. Don't make your visitor wait while you process your new images.

Comment: Neither. If you want to keep resource usage under control use a queue/worker model and restrict the number of workers to whatever satisfies your resource constraints. Artbitrarily waiting for poorly-defined circumstances to maybe do something hopefully isn't going to result in something stable or maintainable.

Comment: Both, anything that scans for file that persists probably should not be ran as multiple processes.  The reason is race conditions: one process could move the files, while another instance is just about to move them just to find they no longer exists and bombs out.  I'd suggest using something like this [ProcLock](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/ProcLock.php)  (which I wrote) and will let you make sure only 1 process is ran by CRON at any given time.  And on the same token as mentioned you should not rely on user page hits for scheduling.

Comment: why not ask the user to press a button when they have finished uploading, seen this on lots of sites

Comment: However as @Sammitch mentions the absolute best way is to use a Queue/Worker system.  This can be as simple as recording jobs in the DB then have a worker scan the DB or it can be as complex as something like RabbitMQ etc.  For example, User uploads file and an entry into DB is made with timestamp, then a background CRON job monitors the DB for entries not marked complete whos timestamp is "past due", then do you thing to said file from record, mark record as completed.  Or something like that.